# How do I extract the music from the game files?

Tags: starcraft-2

I love the Starcraft 2 music.  Is there any way to extract it from the game files?  From there, I can probably transcode it if necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blizzard games typically store all the data in mpq file(s), and StarCraft 2 is no exception. I believe the music files are stored there as well, though I don't know in which format. There are a few tools around for opening the mpq files - [here's an example editor](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html). Keep in mind that if you do find some way to extract the music from the game and transcode it to some convenient format, I'm guessing sharing it could be considered a copyright violation; and I wouldn't be surprised if just extracting any data from it is against some Blizzard policy.

You don't actually have to manually extract the music, however - the StarCraft 2 collector's edition includes a soundtrack CD, which you can also buy independently ([here's one offered in Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XTDMDM), and [Ivo posted a link to iTunes where it's much cheaper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/extract-starcraft-2-music/7461#7461)).

In addition, you might be interested in [this post on GosuGamers](http://www.gosugamers.net/starcraft2/thread/493526-soundtrack-available), which points to a series of YouTube videos with the different tracks.

Comment: Kind of strange that you have to buy the CD off course when you already own the game...

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I may just transcode the flv's if they're high enough quality and MPQ Editor doesn't work.  I don't plan on distributing; I just want something nice to listen to in winamp while I code.

Comment: I used MPQEdit and found all of the music in Mods/Liberty.SC2Mod\base.SC2Assets\Music.  It's already in ogg (my preferred format), so I didn't even have to transcode.  I found about twice as many tracks as the GosuGamers link, and that's not even including the Jukebox music.

Answer (score 5):

There's a soundtrack you can buy ;-)

[image]

[Here's an iTunes link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/starcraft-ii-wings-liberty/id380412701)

Answer (score 4):

I did use the windows [MPQ Editor](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html) to extract the jukebox music, which is in ogg format. I'm running this under Macosx with [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).

Gotta love Zerg, Shotgun, and you. By the way, [Whiteboy James and the Blues Express have a faster version](http://www.whiteboyjames.com/). Somehow I still prefer the jukebox version.

Comment: Where though, Adam? I have been searching and searching for the MPQ file and it's not in my SC2 folder. I'm also searching for the file using software, and I can't find it. So I'm stuck listening to the 2564 or so different World of Warcraft songs.

Comment: There are no files with that extension, at least under MacOSX. MPQ is the name of the file format. I simply looked for the biggest file to open, which got me to StarCraft II/Campaigns/Liberty.SC2Campaign/base.SC2Assets.